# Show Custom Keyboard on Launch

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using the following custom keyboard:

https://github.com/kulpreetchilana/Custom-iOS-Keyboards

How do you make it so that they keyboard is displayed at the beginning without having to touch the text view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the version of iOS you're using (not sure if it works on 8), you can do:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad;
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Or

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews;
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self.textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

In your ViewController.

Answer (score 1):

Tapping a text view will call `becomeFirstResponder` on it.

So you should be able to make the keyboard appear with...

```
[textView becomeFirstResponder];
```

I've never used that framework though so not 100% sure.